# PHP Google Play Subscription API

Tags: php, google-play, subscription

I am trying to get Google Play API subscription details using PHP and using following url  to get purchase data :

```
https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v1/applications/[PACKAGE]/subscriptions/[SKU]/purchases/[PURCHASE_TOKEN]?access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]
```

I am getting the following error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "androidpublisher",
    "reason": "developerDoesNotOwnApplication",
    "message": "This developer account does not own the application."
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "This developer account does not own the application."
 }
}
```

Please help me sort out.

Comment: Why is this tagged `css`?

Comment: I think that URL is for information about that application that you need to own.

Answer (score 1):

Just providing the URL does not help you get data of any application. How can you think so.? Isnt it insecure.? You have to get proper data by which you can at least prove ownership for the app..